# How to paginate when it is impossible to know in advance the limited number of records for 1 page Using Parse Server and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, pagination

I have a number of records as follows:

```
id     |  invoiceId     |  Name  |  Amount  |  Type
1         111111111        Alan      1000       parking
2         111111111        Alan      50         bet
3         222222222        Jonson    800        parking
4         333333333        Peter     1200       parking
5         333333333        Peter     80         bet
6         444444444        Daniel    1000       parking
7         444444444        Daniel    800        bet
8         555555555        Weskee    800        parking
9         666666666        Victor    900        parking
10        666666666        Victor    800        bet
11        777777777        Glensk    800        bet
12        888888888        Nickky    800        bet
13        999999999        Quatick   800        bet
14        121111122        Vincent   800        parking
```

And now i want to get 5 rows for each page, **but for rows with same invoiceId it only counts as 1.**
I expect to get the **first page** result like this:

```
id     |  invoiceId     |  Name  |  Amount  |  Type
null      111111111        Alan      -       -
1         111111111        Alan      1000       parking
2         111111111        Alan      50         bet
3         222222222        Jonson    800        parking
null      333333333        Peter     -          -
4         333333333        Peter     1200       parking
5         333333333        Peter     80         bet
null      444444444        Daniel    -          -
6         444444444        Daniel    1000       parking
7         444444444        Daniel    800        bet
8         555555555        Weskee    800        parking
```

And the second page will look like this:

```
id     |  invoiceId     |  Name  |  Amount  |  Type
null      666666666        Victor    -          -
9         666666666        Victor    900        parking
10        666666666        Victor    800        bet
11        777777777        Glensk    800        bet
12        888888888        Nickky    800        bet
13        999999999        Quatick   800        bet
14        121111122        Vincent   800        parking
```

I'm using the following code to query:

```
recordsQuery.skip(offset * size);
recordsQuery.limit(size);
```

I know that this way cannot solve the pagination problem as I described above.
So can you give me a solution?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [distinct](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#distinct) function?

Comment: I never do it before

Comment: Give it a try. I believe that's the easy way to go.

Comment: Thanks.
But the way you say it is to return rows that are completely duplicated, and in my case only rows with only 2 fields are duplicated.

Comment: No. You can specify the field. It would be something like `query.distinct('invoiceId')`